# What does the (?i)\\. regular expression mean?

Tags: regex, css-selectors

The code uses the following regular expression

`img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)]`

I'm not sure if the `.` is escaped or the `\`

Comment: Some context would be helpful.  Where does this exist?  Is it within a string literal?

Comment: In javascript you can define a regex using a string `new RegExp("img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)]")` or by a regex literal `/img[src~=(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)]/`.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @dana:It is a combination of regex and [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) using a string.

Comment: This is not a valid CSS selector. If it's in a regex, can you paste the actual regex?

Comment: @BoltClock: You're right, it is not valid as a CSS selector in its entirety. It believe you could read it like this; find  tag[attr~=regex]. So the `[attr~=val]` is the CSS selector followed by the regex `(?i)\\.(png|jpe?g)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `\` is escaped, which appears to be an error given what it's trying to do....

actually, you've taken that out of context. that's probably in a string. if it's in a string, then it's escaping the slash, and then *that* slash is escaping the dot.

the `~=` means "ends with" and the `(?i)` switches it into case-insensitive mode.

---

errr... now that i think about it, that actually looks like a hybrid between a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors) (probably used [in jquery](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)) and a regex (being familiar with both syntaxes, I thought nothing of it!). The `~=` doesn't do anything in a regex (they're literal chars) the `[` and `]` represent a character set though.

So...I don't know what the result of this is. I suspect someone got confused and tried mixing the two.

Comment: I'm guessing it is a string.  It almost looks like a jQuery selector for an `<img>` tag with src ending with .png or .jpg or .jpeg.

Comment: Stupid me, of course! It was in a string. But how is `(?i)` different from `.*`.

Comment: (?i) specifies options. It is not part of the expression.

Comment: @ababzy: it's completely different. the `(?i)` makes everything that follows case insensitive. my guess is that they wanted case-insensitive file extensions. the `(?i)` doesnt actually match anything itself.

Comment: @Mark: Makes perfect sense now. It is a definitely a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

It means match case insensitively, any string that ends in:

- \.png
- \.jpeg
- \.jpg

But this is dependant on context. If used in a context, were \ need to be escaped out at a higher level, then it means match case insensitively:

- .png
- .jpeg
- .jpg

Answer (score 0):

In this expression , '/' is escaped ,which in turn escapes the '.'